# Racket: how check the size of list?

Tags: racket

i need help with racket

```
(define size1 (lambda (m)
               (printf "size is ~v" (length m))))
```

test it

```
>(size1 '(2 8 9 0 'uu 98 0))
size is 7
```

which is fine

,

but second test

```
> (size1 '((((7) 9 (11)))))
size is 1
```

it is give me that 1, cuz of the brocket, However

what i want to provide is 3

i need help with that

Answer (score 2):

Note the following:

```
'((((7) 9 (11))))           ; list with one element --> '(((7) 9 (11)))
'(((7) 9 (11)))             ; list with one element --> '((7) 9 (11))
'((7) 9 (11))               ; list with 3 elements  --> '(7), 9 and '(11)
```

If you intended to write a list with three elements, then your list should be `'((7) 9 (11))`, and your function call becomes:

```
> (size1 '((7) 9 (11)))
size is 3
```

Answer (score 1):

So you would like to count the elements that are not null and not pairs:

```
(define (count-atoms tree)
  (cond ((null? tree) 0)       ; an empty tree has 0 atoms
        ((not (pair? tree)) 1) ; an atom is exactly one atom
        (else ???)))           ; the sum of counting atoms in car and cdr
```

This is very similar to how `length` is made.